# In maple, how to create a sequence of alternating variables?

Tags: list, nested-lists, maple

I'm quite new to **Maple** and I would like to create the following list:

```
U__N := u__1[0], u__2[0], u__1[1], u__2[1], u__1[2], u__2[2], u__1[3], u__2[3], u__1[4], u__2[4], u__1[5], u__2[5]
```

I came up with the following two options. For both I lack the knowledge for the last step

### Option 1

```
U__N := seq([u__1[k], u__2[k]], k = 0 .. 5)
```

which gives me a nested list:  `U__N := [u__1[0], u__2[0]], [u__1[1], u__2[1]], [u__1[2], u__2[2]], [u__1[3], u__2[3]], [u__1[4], u__2[4]], [u__1[5], u__2[5]]`. However, now I do not know how to "un-nest" the nested list.

### Option 2:

Create two separate lists

```
U__N2 := seq(u__2[k], k = 0 .. 5 - 1)
```

which returns `U__N1 := u__1[0], u__1[1], u__1[2], u__1[3], u__1[4]`

```
U__N2 := seq(u__2[k], k = 0 .. 5 - 1)
```

which returns `U__N2 := u__2[0], u__2[1], u__2[2], u__2[3], u__2[4]`.
Now I would like to concatenate/combine these two lists alternatively.

Do you have any suggestions for one of these two options or an alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to create the pair-wise portions and then utilize those directly, than to form the whole list-of-lists and `Flatten` it.

The special-evaluation rules of the `seq` command allows for its first argument to not be evaluated until *after* `k` attains concrete numeric values.

This allow you to adjust your first method and extract the operands of the pair-wise inner lists, using the `op` command.

```
seq(op([u__1[k], u__2[k]]), k = 0 .. 5);

   u__1[0], u__2[0], u__1[1], u__2[1],
   u__1[2], u__2[2], u__1[3], u__2[3],
   u__1[4], u__2[4], u__1[5], u__2[5]

seq([u__1[k], u__2[k]][], k = 0 .. 5);

   u__1[0], u__2[0], u__1[1], u__2[1],
   u__1[2], u__2[2], u__1[3], u__2[3],
   u__1[4], u__2[4], u__1[5], u__2[5]
```

The trailing `[]` in `[...][]` acts like `op([...])`.

Answer (score 1):

using [Flatten](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=ListTools%2FFlatten) gave me the desired solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).